# How to dynamically refer to a property

Tags: sapui5

Here is the view. In the view I'm trying to read en properties value and I'm trying to make it dynamic.

```
<VBox items="{mDialog>/data/en}">
                    <VBox></VBox>
</VBox>
```

I'm trying to pass "en" dynamically so that it can point to "fr" as well.

Here is the model data

```
data: {
                            en: [
                                {
                                    type: "Scale",
                                    name: 1,
                                    shortDescription: "Lalala1",
                                    longDescription: "uh la la la1"
                                }
                            ],
                            fr: [
                                {
                                    type: "Scale",
                                    name: 1,
                                    shortDescription: "FR Lalala1",
                                    longDescription: "FR uh la la la1"
                                }
                            ],
                            de: [
                                {
                                    type: "Scale",
                                    name: 1,
                                    shortDescription: "FR Lalala1",
                                    longDescription: "FR uh la la la1"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
```

Comment: Use a formatter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think that you can do that, because Views are not preprocessing  binding strings you enter that way. So you cant dynamically name the property that way.

What you can do is use the `.bindProperty` method.

Give your element an id.
In your controller, onInit, you

```
var oMyElement = this.byId(this.createId("<its id>"));
var oLanguage = "en";
oMyElement.bindProperty("items", { path: oLanguage } );
```

or something like that

See this thread:
[SAP UI5- Dynamic Property Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67419955/sap-ui5-dynamic-property-binding)